# How to get message returned by SQL stored procedure in Powershell to a notepad

Tags: mysql, sql, powershell

I have to run a stored procedure from Powershell and I am able to do it. The stored procedure does not return anything but prints some value in the Messages section (please see below)

[image: Results|Messages]

I need to output this value returned under messages in a notepad in powershell. Below is the code I tried but doesn't work. Please help.

```
    $out1 = $command.ExecuteReader();
    $out1.Read()
    $out2=$out1[1]
    $out2 | Out-File $outFile -Append
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Where are you running into a problem?

Comment: What command is being used within the stored procedure to generate the "Purge Completed..." string? Print? Also, when you say _it doesn't work_ what is the result (if any)?

Comment: What library are you using to access the database e.g., ADO.NET, etc.?

Comment: @FDavidov The command PRINT is used. The result is 0 since return value is 0.

Comment: @JacobColvin The message was displayed by the PRINT command and I am not able to get it out in a notepad.

Comment: i am using ADO.NET @Adam

Comment: @NareshArvind, the `PRINT` command is an addition made available almost solely for debugging purposes. **PURE** SQL does not include using this function to communicate with other processes. That's why you are not getting any result. The way to **_LEGALLY_** get an output from a stored procedure is via an OUTPUT parameter or (depending on the DBMS) using a `SELECT <result variable>` as the last command of your routine. In other words, what you are trying to do will never ever work with PRINT.